# When I change value in Shared Preference app got crash

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnfQt.png

As shown above From settings when I change the value of temprature units from metric to imperial and press back button my app got crash and showing below error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBeHk.png

SettingsActivity

```
    package com.example.poo.sunshine;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.ListPreference;
    import android.preference.Preference;
    import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

    public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new MyPreferenceFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Add 'general' preferences, defined in the XML file
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

            // For all preferences, attach an OnPreferenceChangeListener so the UI summary can be
            // updated when the preference changes.
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            Preference locationPref = findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key));
            Preference unitsPref = findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_units_key));
            prefChanged(sharedPreferences, locationPref, key);
            prefChanged(sharedPreferences, unitsPref, key);
        }

        private void prefChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, Preference pref, String key) {
            if (sharedPreferences instanceof ListPreference) {
                // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
                // the preference's 'entries' list (since they have separate labels/values).
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) sharedPreferences;
                int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(key);
                if (prefIndex >= 0) {
                    pref.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
                } else {
                    pref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
                }    
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem is, that your fragment is not added to the activity anymore. You can check with the method `isAdded()` if it is before using the preferences: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded%28%29

Comment: ya sure ok let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is cause from the view of your Fragment is not yet attached to your SettingActivity.

To avoid this error, you can check with [isAdded()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()) before access views in your Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if(isAdded()){
            Preference locationPref = findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key));
            Preference unitsPref = findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_units_key));
            prefChanged(sharedPreferences, locationPref, key);
            prefChanged(sharedPreferences, unitsPref, key);
        }

}
```

Another solution and I would like to suggest as well.
You should register the preference changed listener in `onViewCreated()` in your Fragment. So that mean your Fragment is fully attached.

```
 @Override
 public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity())
        .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
 }
```

Hope this will work!

Comment: let me try...thanx for answering my question

Comment: do i need to add both the things ?? isAdded() method and register the preference change?

Comment: Just one of these solutions :) but I think my suggested solution is better.

Comment: isAdded() method worked for me thank you so much :)   but I don't understand one thing I already created fragment in Activity then y do I need to add it again ???

Comment: You confuse isAdded() method. It not add your Fragment to Activity again. It just check the status while it is adding to Activity.